# How would I draw the Max Thickness Sweep Angle on a wing from a Top View?

Tags: wing, fixed-wing, wing-sweep

I have the Max Thickness Sweep Angle, Wing Tip and Root Chord Length, and Max Thickness to Chord Ratio defined. However, I am having trouble drawing the Max Thickness Sweep Angle on the wing because I'm not sure where to start on the root relative to the Leading Edge of the wing. In essence, I am trying to find where the Max Thickness Sweep Angle is on the root and tip of the wing from a Top View of the wing. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Start where the wing is thickest?

Comment: Do you have root and tip airfoils? If not, you will fail.